# When adding multiple pages with Routes, why do all of my pages load at once when I'm on my "homepage"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-dom

I'm relatively somewhat new to the whole world of react, DOM, etc.

This probably sounds like a simple issue or a dumb question, bear with me.

My code for the routing stuff looks like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="content">
      <SideBar>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={Dashboard} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </SideBar>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

My SideBar is a component of a sidebar, it should allow users to click on a button and to navigate to a new page. In this case, a dashboard. However, all pages basically load at the start of me going to my localhost/

I've tested this out due to a console.log loading from the dashboard basically popping up in other places, not just localhost/dashboard.

I'm using MaterialUI, React.
My SideBar.js looks like this:

```
  <List>
    {BarData.map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <ListItemButton
          key={key}
          onClick={() => {
            window.location.pathname = item.link;
          }}
```

Has things removed, but here is my SideBar data (in another folder).

```
export const BarData = [
  {
    text: "Dashboard",
    icon: <HomeRounded color="#637381" />,
    link: "/dashboad",
  },
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm completely new to React, DOM, etc. So I'm unsure if this is the best way to go in general.

In short, what I'm trying to achieve is:

- Have multiple pages, if a user clicks a button, it'll navigate them to that specific page, in this case a Dashboard.
- Not have every page load at once(?) I'm still unsure on why this is, is it due to me importing the dashboard page and the element is grabbing it, not working fully, so it's just loading what the page shows?